# StackOverflowError building a tree

Tags: scala

I'm trying to build a Tree where one node can have multiple children (see below). When I try to run the App below, I get the following in the declaration of the Data case class

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

What does this mean?

```
// data: information stored in the node
// list: list of children nodes
// parent: pointer to the parent
case class Node[A] ( data: A, var list: List[Node[A]], var parent: Node[A] ) 

case class Data (descrip: String)

object Tree extends App {

   val root = Node(Data("root"),null,null)

    val node1 = Node(Data("node1"),null,root)
    val node2 = Node(Data("node2"),null,root)
    val list = List(node1, node2)

    root.list = list 

    println(root)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your structure has a infinite cycle. `root.list` contains `node1` and `node2` and these contain `root`.

It tries to print (*) `root`, but to print `root` it needs to print `nodes` 1 and 2, but to print these it needs to print `root` and so on, never ending, eventually blowing up the stack, which is the thing in the JVM that stores method calls information.

(*) The word "print" is used here rather loosely, it is actually the calls to `object.toString` for each of `object`s involved.